# How to make main thread to wait until other threads ends

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a method:

```
public void Run()
{
    instalProgressPageViewModel.ExecuteButton_Click();
    //waiting here
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Method Execute_Click() calls a installers of msi packages. Those installers run in separate threads:

```
this.uiDispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
            new InstallationCompleted(this.completeInstallDelegate),
            installationState);
```

where:

```
this.completeInstallDelegate // method which should be called after the thread is done.
```

Waiting for function `CompleteInstall` is crucial as its finalize installation  and begins installation next msi package in a list of packages.

In the sample code of method `Run` app is closed before anything can happen.
I tried putting:

```
while(true){}
```

In a place of  `// waiting here` and put breakpoint in `CompleteInstall` method to check if it will be called but it wasn't hit. App is stucked in infite loop inside while.

What can I do to force my main thread to wait for threads and jump into `completeinstall` method when its called by delegate?

@Update:

With your suggestions my code looks like this:

there is

```
public static ManualResetEvent mre // global object initialized in main
```

and  other class is:

```
public void Run()
{    
    instalProgressPageViewModel.ExecuteButton_Click();
    mre.WaitOne();
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

ExecuteButton_Click call this function:

```
    public void StartProcessing()
    {
        var processor = new Action(this.DoProcessing);
        processor.BeginInvoke(null, null);
    }
```

now DoProcessing:

```
private void DoProcessing()
    {
        var installationState = this.Execute();
        // Schedule the update function in the UI thread.
        this.uiDispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
            new InstallationCompleted(this.completeInstallDelegate),
            installationState);
    }
```

and finally completeInstallDelegate

```
private void CompleteInstall(InstallationState installationState)
    {
        App.mre.Set();
        /* 
         Some code
         */

        this.PostInstallAndNext();
    }
```

If I put break Point at the line `App.mre.Set()` it is never hit.
and for unknow reason for me the `DoProcessing` is called after `mre.WaitOne()`. Does Action and BeginInvoke work out of sync too?

Comment: Maybe thread.Join() helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for updating the question.
It looks like you are never creating an actual new Thread, i.e. you are suspending the main thread and effectively deadlocking your application.

You could create an new `Thread` here:

```
public void StartProcessing()
{
    var thread = new Thread(() => this.DoProcessing);
    thread.Start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks!. Will check it in a moment. If I'm not creating new thread so why that delegate isn't called?

Comment: Ok I found sollution. My code above is part of wpf app. In case of specific command line switches it should run in silent mode without calling wpf windows. Thats why dispacher isn't working because it wont work without wpf controls

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `ManualResetEvent` class.

Create a `ManualResetEvet`

```
ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
```

In the `Main` method wait for this event to get signalled.

```
mre.WaitOne();
```

In your delegate (when the work is finished), signal the event.

```
mre.Set();
```

Comment: Thanks. But now I'm considering that the problem wasn't in waiting. at this moment app is waiting at `WaitOne` and the delegate is not called

Comment: Are you sure you created and started the worker thread before you called `WaitOne`?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to use [`ManualResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.threading.manualresetevent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You would then have a blocking call to `WaitOne`, until you call `Set` from the other thread.